# Как лучше всего реализовать постоянную проверку изменений в таблице sqlite3 в тг. боте на aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

В таблице есть параметр, который обновляется с определенным действием.
Например опыт за каждое сообщение, в котором больше 100 символом.
При достижении 100 опыта бот повышает уровень на 1

Как лучше всего сделать постоянную проверку, чтобы максимально быстро ловить момент достижения 100 опыта для оправки сообщения о повышении уровня. С учетом не сильной нагрузки на сервер.

Такая функция нужна мне для предотвращения таких событий как переизбыток опыта и не своевременное повышение уровня.

Грубо говоря мне нужен обработчик события, который при достижения определенных условий будет незамедлительно выполнять функцию.

Надеюсь я понятно объяснил, буду рад если подскажите как реализовать это.

Comment: в момент обновления значения вам ведь точно известна его величина. зачкм же тогда нужны ещё какме-то дополнительные сущности?

Comment: функция уведомления о повешения уровня у меня идет отдельно от функции выдачи опыта.
т.к. функций выдачи опыта у меня несколько, за разные действия.  

Я понимаю  что могу внедрить в функции выдачи опыта, функцию уведомления. Но я хочу узнать, это единственный вариант или можно как-то упросить?